# Worn out (stripped) screws in Macbook Pro - how to remove?

Tags: macbook-pro

I was planning to remove my cdrom and add a second HD in my Macbook Pro (2011), but I can't remove the screws. It seems they are stripped, even though I've been really careful (they are really tight).

[Some images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xoWo.jpg)

Anyone had a similar problem before? Which is the best way to remove them? Would Apple authorized places remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use locking pliers to take it off, then take the screw to a local fastenings store who should be able to sell you a similarly sized screw with exactly the same thread.

You may want to add Loctite, Apple usually uses Blue 242 Loctite on their screws. You can get cheaper brands, but make sure it's coloured blue — that's the strength of the glue.